# Desplegando app laravel en VPS con Apache

Tags: laravel, apache2

En el archivo 000-default de apache redirecciono de esta forma mi aplicacion.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/App-web-facturas/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Pero al dirigirme a la direccion de mi proyecto lo que me muestra es el contenido del index.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta configurado tu servidor apache para procesar PHP?

Comment: @JonnathanQ instale las exenciones de PHP

Comment: Lo resolvi aplicando esto. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242495/laravel-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server